# Bootstrap buttons far right in table-row, not cell-like

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, html-table

I'm trying to recreate the kind of layout that you can see in the following picture:

[image: mock up of what I want]

I can't find how to put buttons at the end of each row without them being in a cell.  If it have to be in a cell, I would want to remove all the decoration of that cell to make it look like "outside" of the table.

Any ideas how to do this with bootstrap?

My html looks like this for the moment:

```
        <div class="table-responsive">
            <table class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Date</th>
                        <th>Heure</th>
                        <th>Appel</th>
                        <th>En vente</th>
                        <th>En vente web</th>
                        <th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2014-12-01</td>
                        <td>20:00</td>
                        <td>141201</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                            </a>
                            &nbsp;
                            <a href="">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2014-12-02</td>
                        <td>20:00</td>
                        <td>141202</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok"></span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                            </a>
                            &nbsp;
                            <a href="">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>2014-12-03</td>
                        <td>20:00</td>
                        <td>141203</td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <div class="text-center">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span>
                            </div>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <a href="">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
                            </a>
                            &nbsp;
                            <a href="">
                                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
                            </a>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div><!-- table-responsive -->
```

Comment: I would advise against it from UX perspective - when the buttons are in the same table row, a user can quickly understand that they affect that row, but placing them outside of the table can create a confusion. A better solution is to only show this cell content if the user hover that row.

Answer (score 3):

Try applying a class like this to your cells that should appear "disconnected":

```
.table.table-striped .minimal_cell {
    background: none;
    border-width: 0;
}
```

Apply to the cells containing the icons:

```
<td class="minimal_cell">
    <a href="">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span>
    </a>
    &nbsp;
    <a href="">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>
    </a>
</td>
```

jsFiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/eum3sn97/2/

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  It works as expected.  Is it that bad to use !important if there is no alternative?

Comment: Actually, you don't need the `!important` - I just looked again and it works without it.  Answer and jsFiddle updated to reflect that.